# use case to find percentage - SELECT CASE subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, case, percentage

pretty much a beginner with MySQL. learning through Lynda.com at moment.

I have a database with following tables

```
tblmatches - matchID, matchdate, matchtime, matchstatus, teamhomeID,    teamAwayID, matchscorehome, matchscoreaway, seasonID, competitonID
tblteam - teamID, teamName
```

I am trying to find out how many games, per team, where both teams scored.

I am using the following statement which finds the number of games played (p), how many of said games did both teams score (y) but can't work out how to get the percent.

I'm grouping by teamName and it must use both home and away games

```
SELECT
teamName AS Team, 
Sum(P) AS P,
SUM(Y) AS Y
FROM(
    SELECT
    teamHomeID Team,
    1 P,
    CASE WHEN matchScoreHome AND matchScoreAway > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Y 
    FROM tblmatches WHERE matchstatus = 'FT' AND competitionID = 1         AND     seasonID = 2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
   teamAwayID,
   1,
   CASE WHEN matchScoreHome AND matchScoreAway > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Y
  FROM tblmatches WHERE matchstatus = 'FT' AND competitionID = 1 AND      seasonID = 2
  ) as tab
 JOIN tblteam t ON tab.team=t.teamID
 GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY SUM(Y) DESC ;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer, as still learning hadn't realised mysql works but starting with whats in between quotes.  AT that point I realised that SUM had to be outside the subquery, a little searching via google and knew to put in initial SELECT

```
SELECT
teamName AS Team, 
Sum(P) AS P,
SUM(Y) AS Y,
(SUM(Y) * 100) / SUM(P) AS 'BTTS PCT'
FROM(
    SELECT
    teamHomeID Team,
    1 P,
    CASE
    WHEN matchScoreHome AND matchScoreAway > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
   END Y 
  FROM tblmatches WHERE matchstatus = 'FT' AND competitionID = 1        AND seasonID = 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
   teamAwayID,
   1,
   CASE 
    WHEN matchScoreHome AND matchScoreAway > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END Y
   FROM tblmatches WHERE matchstatus = 'FT' AND competitionID = 1 AND   seasonID = 2 
   ) as tab
  JOIN tblteam t ON tab.team=t.teamID
 GROUP BY Team
 ORDER BY SUM(Y) DESC ;
```